# Would redraw() not cause CSS reapply?

Tags: css, eclipse

Because this [problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362532), I don't want to use the mechanism of Eclipse CSS pseudo. I want to use CSS Class to achieve dynamic effect indirectly .

Here is the test code :

```java
Shell shell = new Shell() ;
shell.setSize( 200, 100 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
 
Composite composite = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE ) ;
Button button = new Button( composite, SWT.CHECK ) ;
button.setSize( 100, 50 ) ;
button.setData( CSSSWTConstants.CSS_CLASS_NAME_KEY, "selected" ) ;

shell.open() ;
```

CSS :

```css
Button {
    background-color: black;
}

Button[class=selected] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

result :
[image] The css code is correct.

Then I adjust the code :

```java
Shell shell = new Shell() ;
shell.setSize( 200, 100 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;

Composite composite = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE ) ;
Button button = new Button( composite, SWT.CHECK ) ;
button.setSize( 100, 50 ) ;
button.addListener( SWT.Selection, e -> {
    if ( button.getSelection() ) {
        button.setData( CSSSWTConstants.CSS_CLASS_NAME_KEY, "selected" ) ;
    } else {
        button.setData( CSSSWTConstants.CSS_CLASS_NAME_KEY, null ) ;
    }
    button.redraw() ;
} ) ;

shell.open() ;
```

But it does not work, the background of this button is always black. Even if I invoke `button.redraw();` in the selection listener.

[image]
[image]

Is css only used when creating controls ? Even if invoking `redraw()` would not cause CSS reapply?

Comment: Do not refer to some third party site for "this problem". That site information may change or disappear 30 seconds from now. Post the information here, within your question. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just settings the class name in the data only works when creating the control.

Once it has to been created you must use the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IStylingEngine` interface to change the class name:

```java
@Inject
IStylingEngine engine

....

engine.setClassname(control, "class name");
```

You can also set the class name in the data as before and call

```
engine.style(control);
```